# Configuring ssl in tomcat6

Tags: ssl, tomcat6

How to configure ssl for testing on local machine with windows and tomcat6 to enter sites like http://localhost:8443?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start with the SSL Configuration HOWTO located at:  [Tomcat 6 SSL HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)